How can I apply payment using shopify API?
I’m working on a third-party solution for automating reordering. I need to create a new order based on a client’s order and process automatic payment for it. Here’s my plan for how to proceed:

Create the order (copy all information from the original, so the shipping address will use the client’s details).
Change the billing address to my company’s address.
Automatically apply payment (without redirects, etc.) using my payment method (e.g., Stripe).
The payment is made by a third party, not the store.

The payment must be processed automatically, without manual intervention.
Once the payment is completed, the order will be marked as complete and moved to processing.
The challenge I face is with the payment process. For example, I have a Stripe account for payment handling, but it’s unclear how to integrate the transaction with Shopify’s workflow (or execute the transaction through Shopify’s API) to move the order through the process.
Could you help me understand which API would be suitable for this case?
I found some endpoints to create / process orders:
create draft order: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-10/mutations/draftOrderCreate
create order from draft order
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-10/mutations/draftOrderComplete
Captures payment for an authorized transaction on an order. But I don't see how to apply transaction for this
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-10/mutations/orderCapture
